# The page i am developing is scrolling to the right. I dont want that scroll

Tags: html, css

The page i am developing is scrolling to the right.

I don't want that scroll because pages do not scroll to right. Right?

Just help me remove that scroll.

I have used html5 and css only.

Here is the CSS file:

```css
/***********************************Basic layout****************************/
*{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
}
.bg{
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 background: url('1.jpg');
 height: 700px;
 width:100%;
 opacity:1;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}
body{
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 margin:0px;
 right:0px;
}
/*************top header and navigation bar******************************/
header{
 position:relative;
 top:20px;
 left:50px;
 font-size:1.3em;
}
nav{
 position:relative;
 left:600px;
 top:-47px;
}
nav ul li{
 list-style:none;
 display:inline;
 padding:10px;
 font-size:1.1em;
}
a{
 color:#444;
 text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
 border-bottom: 4px solid #438d80;/*#438d80*/
}
#message{
 position:relative;
 top:50px;
 left:450px;
}
#message p{
 color:white;
 font-size:30px; 
}
p{
 line-height:8px;
}
/*
.button{
 height:40px;
 width:200px;
 background:#438d80;
 border:none;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:20px;
 position:relative;
 left:490px;
 top:55px;
 color:#eee;
 font-weight:100;
 letter-spacing:1.7px;
 border-radius:5px;
}
.button:hover{
 color:white;
 background:#ff9933;
}*/
#earnButton{
 position:realtive;
 top:55px;
 left:-100px;
 background:#438d80;
}
#container2{
 position:absolute;
 top:710px;
 text-align:center;
}
#container2 > h1{
 text-align:center; 
}
```

Comment: Add your HTML please!

Comment: Maybe because there is a div inside your html which take more space than the width of screen, but we can't help without html provided

Answer (score 1):

For body tag write overflow-x: hidden like this

```
body
{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

It will fix scroll issue.